# multiple wired wap from different vendor

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

My configuration:

```
                  ISP
                   |
     4G+ modem TP-Link Archer MR600 (router + AP)
         /                         \  
        /                           \
    LAN 1 STA(s)                   NETGEAR JWNR2015v5 (AP only) 
                                           |
                                           |
                                      LAN 2 STA(s)
```

I want:

- the NETGEAR to be a wireless AP only
- LAN 2 and LAN 1 to be ONLY ONE LAN (TP-Link is the DHCP server and gateway)
- connect the TP-Link and the NETGEAR via ethernet (no wifi bridge)

I think I need this connection:

```
TP-LINK (LAN port) <>--------<> (LAN port) NETGEAR
```

**Is this correct?** I do not connect the WAN port of the NETGEAR (I am referring to the labels on the physical plugs on the devices)

Any hint regarding the best settings on the two devices (both for wired and wireless interfaces...).

I want the two APs to broadcast the same SSID and PSWD so that the STA(s) can seamlessly roam from one AP to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally need your secondary AP (netgear) in bridge mode (or the vendor-equivalent name for the setting) to get it to forward DHCP requests from wifi clients out its lan ports. Bridge mode often* lets you use the wan port as another lan port, but lan-to-lan for the cabling works best.

WiFi roaming can depend on a lot of stuff to feel "seamless" (mostly on your clients), but yeah your planned setup looks fine

Comment: Ok, now I am using the wan port and I cannot access the NETGEAR configuration page anymore... I gues there's some buggy firewall rules because I see IPs of STA on the secondary AP to appear on the wired list of the primary DHCP (tp-link) so the bridge seems to work. I will try to switch the port to LAN